# Need oracle query to select the order by

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-order-by, case

Table contains value 1,2,3 but while display the values needs to show 2,1,3

Example

```
Table A

    column1      column2   column3
    1            Rat       Animals
    2            Parrot    Bird
    3            Lotus     Flower
```

Need to display parrot first then Rat and Lotus which means 2,1,3

**Expected Output:**

```
    column1      column2   column3
    2            Parrot    Bird
    1            Rat       Animal
    3            Lotus     Flower
```

Kindly help me out to fix the issue in order by query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **CASE** expression in the **ORDER BY** clause for the particular conditions, and let other rows retain their order.

**Setup**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t
  2      (column1 int, column2 varchar2(6), column3 varchar2(7));

Table created.

SQL> INSERT ALL
  2      INTO t (column1, column2, column3)
  3           VALUES (1, 'Rat', 'Animals')
  4      INTO t (column1, column2, column3)
  5           VALUES (2, 'Parrot', 'Bird')
  6      INTO t (column1, column2, column3)
  7           VALUES (3, 'Lotus', 'Flower')
  8      INTO t (column1, column2, column3)
  9           VALUES (7, 'def', 'xyz')
 10      INTO t (column1, column2, column3)
 11           VALUES (4, 'abc', 'qwe')
 12  SELECT * FROM dual;

5 rows created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.
```

**Table Data**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

   COLUMN1 COLUMN COLUMN3
---------- ------ -------
         1 Rat    Animals
         2 Parrot Bird
         3 Lotus  Flower
         7 def    xyz
         4 abc    qwe
```

**Required Query**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t
  2   ORDER BY
  3    CASE column1
  4       WHEN 1
  5          THEN 2
  6       WHEN 2
  7          THEN 1
  8       ELSE 3
  9    END,
 10   column1;

   COLUMN1 COLUMN COLUMN3
---------- ------ -------
         2 Parrot Bird
         1 Rat    Animals
         3 Lotus  Flower
         4 abc    qwe
         7 def    xyz

SQL>
```

So, you have your **desired order** as well as the other rows retain their order as specified.

Answer (score 0):

That is a strange order requested, anyways try this -

```
SELECT Column1,Column2,Column3
FROM TableA
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Column1 = 2 THEN 1 
              WHEN Column1 = 1 THEN 2
              ELSE 3 
         END
```

Comment: It is not complete because you are leaving the other rows in **random**. What if there are other values `4, 5, 6` you will lose the order for other rows. When you use `CASE` in `ORDER BY`, you should take care of the other rows not mentioned int the case expression.

Comment: @LalitKumarB     
The request was made for 3 rows and o/p was requested based on that. My query will do the work, if the requirement is different then solution will be different.

Comment: @user2000189 - please accept this as the answer if it helped.